# Walking around a sphere in Lumberyard

Tags: lua, lumberyard-engine

I am trying to create a simple game using Amazon Lumberyard and my goal is to have levels/stages where the player will be able to walk around a mini planet.

I have seen a lot of tutorials about this for Unity, but I find it hard to try to translate this into Lua.

My problem is trying to make the "Feet" of the character point towards the planet. Any help would be appreciated.

the script I got for unity is below,

Planet

```
public class PlanetScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float gravity = -12;

public void Attract(Transform playerTransform)
{
    Vector3 gravityUp = (playerTransform.position - transform.position).normalized;
    Vector3 localUp = playerTransform.up;

    playerTransform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(gravityUp * gravity);

    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(localUp, gravityUp) * playerTransform.rotation;
    playerTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(playerTransform.rotation, targetRotation, 50f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

and the player has

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (attractorPlanet)
    {
        attractorPlanet.Attract(playerTransform);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a method for pointing the feet you found in Unity, and highlight the parts you need help translating into Lumberyard's Lua API?

Comment: Actually if you know how to do the "Quaternion.FromToRotation" using Lumberyard's api, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

My Lua is pretty rusty but functionally there are several ways to do this.
The easiest may be to set your characters rotation (Quaternion or Vector).
If you create a new vector which is the result of playerPosition - planetPosition, you want to make this your players new Up Vector (I would normalize this vector).

You can either a) get the rotation of this vector and then set your players rotation vector.
Or b) convert this vector to a quaternion and then setting your players rotation quaternion.

Quaternions are the best!

Comment: Quick question, what is the difference between using quaternion and vector3? I know that vector 3 represents the xyz axis, but I am not familiar with quaternions. I am interested in this because it seems I would be using a lot of it? although I am not sure.

Comment: @Nerdicon euler angles (the vec3 approach) have lock up problem at some angles. Quaternions don't. Quaternions are almost always better, the only exception I can think of right now is the camera

Comment: @ShotgunEmmet thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately I have not yet solved the problem, I have already done PlayerP - PlanetP = V3 but I have no idea how to make this the "up" of the character. What I did was to make a new vector with the original x and y of the players then use the z value of the V3. I hope it made sense.